# Babel <v.6 doesn't transpile native Promises

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I have an ES6 codebase and I run babel via Gulp. Babel's version is 5.8.3 and I run it through babelify which is 6.4.0 and it uses babel version of 5.8.34. I read that babel 6+ needs presets to do transpiling but since I use older version I doesn't need them. After transpiling my code

```
            browserify({
                entries: fileName,
                debug: true
            })
            .ignore('...')
            .transform(
                babelify
            )
            .bundle()
```

My bundle doesn't contain fat arrows, nor const keywords so it seems that transpiling worked but I DO have native js promises which makes my application not to run in IE. :S

I'm clueless what to check next :/

Comment: What would you expect promise to transpile into? You rather need to include a `Promise` polyfill for browsers that don't provide them natively.

Comment: I see, i have babel-polyfill included in my project. But maybe I should double-check if the polyfill really gets included or not. Thanks